# Exporting Business Account attributes with Acumatica API

Tags: acumatica

Our Business Accounts in Acumatica have 13 custom Attributes for our main Business Account Class.  I've been able to save values to the Attributes successfully, based on Acumatica's example "Adding Records to the Business Accounts and Opportunities Forms".  But I have not been able to figure out how to retrieve the values with an Export.

First, I tried using a format similar to how the field was specified when saving them.

```
 Public Function GetCustomerAttributes(ByVal customerID As String) As String()()
    Dim customer As CR303000Content = m_context.CR303000GetSchema()
    m_context.CR303000Clear()

    Dim idFilter As Filter = New Filter()
    idFilter.Field = customer.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount
    idFilter.Condition = FilterCondition.Equals
    idFilter.Value = customerID

    ' SIMILAR TO EXAMPLE FOR SAVING
    Dim awdField As Field = New Field()
    awdField.ObjectName = customer.Attributes.Attribute.ObjectName
    awdField.FieldName = "AWD Number"

    Dim searchfilters() As Filter = {idFilter}
    Dim searchCommands() As Command = {awdField}
    Dim searchResult As String()() = m_context.CR303000Export(searchCommands, searchfilters, 0, False, False)
    Return searchResult
End Function
```

I thought this would return one result with the value for our attribute named "AWD Number".  Instead, it returned 13 results, one for each attribute, and the value of each one was blank.  I changed the FieldName to customer.Attributes.Attribute.FieldName and then it started returning the name of each attribute.  So I thought if I added another field for the value, then I might get the name and value in separate results, like this:

```
Public Function GetCustomerAttributes(ByVal customerID As String) As String()()
    Dim customer As CR303000Content = m_context.CR303000GetSchema()
    m_context.CR303000Clear()

    Dim idFilter As Filter = New Filter()
    idFilter.Field = customer.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount
    idFilter.Condition = FilterCondition.Equals
    idFilter.Value = customerID

    Dim awdField As Field = New Field()
    awdField.ObjectName = customer.Attributes.Attribute.ObjectName
    awdField.FieldName = customer.Attributes.Attribute.FieldName

    Dim awdValue As Field = New Field()
    awdValue.ObjectName = customer.Attributes.Attribute.ObjectName
    awdValue.FieldName = customer.Attributes.Attribute.Value

    Dim searchfilters() As Filter = {idFilter}
    Dim searchCommands() As Command = {awdField, awdValue}
    Dim searchResult As String()() = m_context.CR303000Export(searchCommands, searchfilters, 0, False, False)
    Return searchResult
End Function
```

I did get a 2-item array back for each of the 13 results, but the value in the second field was still blank.

Does anyone know how I can get the values?  I don't really care if I have to get them one at a time, but I'd prefer to get them all at once with their names or codes so that I don't have to rely on the indices always staying the same.  Below are images of the debugger running on my second example and view in Acumatica.  Thanks!

[image: Debugger for 2nd example]

[image: Attributes in Acumatica]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is correct, however you're not using the right object name and field name. The system will dynamically add fields to the primary object (view) of the screen, in this case the object name represented by `customer.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount.ObjectName variable` (I suggest you use the debugger to see what this value equals too - good learning exercise).

The attribute field name will use the same naming convention as used in [How To Retrieve An Attribute Field In StockItems In Acumatica API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079712/how-to-retrieve-an-attribute-field-in-stockitems-in-acumatica-api). The naming convention is _Attributes. The attribute ID is *not* the attribute name; I don't see your configuration but I doubt in your case the Attribute ID is "AWD Number". To summarize, the code will look like:

```
Dim awdField As Field = New Field()
awdField.ObjectName = customer.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount.ObjectName
awdField.FieldName = "AWDNumber_Attributes"
```

In your example, by putting the `Attributes.Attribute.ObjectName` object, the system will iterate through all values inside this table, and then return for every row the fields you want. I'm not exactly sure why you're not seeing all the attribute values in this case, but I think you should be fine with the example above.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had tried that format for the FieldName in my first example, but definitely hadn't tried that ObjectName.  I was convinced it should be referencing Attributes